# Silverlight for windows embedded using WEST tool

Tags: c++, silverlight, baml

I am using silverlight for windows embedded. I have two projects in source control:

1. the Expression Blend project with the UI
2. the VC++ project with the back end code for even handlers

The VC++ project has a resource file .rc and a Generated.rc2 file. Inside the rc2 file there are these lines:

> IDR_SEALPENDANT_APP      SLWE_XAML DISCARDABLE "SDK2wince7 (ARMv4I)\Debug\App.Compressed"
>   IDR_SEALPENDANT_MAINPAGE SLWE_XAML DISCARDABLE "SDK2wince7 (ARMv4I)\Debug\MainPage.Compressed"

The problem is when I try to build the VC++ project it gives an error that the above mentioned files do not exist in the Debug folder. 
If I modify the Expression blend project and run the WEST (Windows Embedded Silverlight Tools) in the VC++ project, it does pick up all the changes. However it still gives the error about the missing compressed files.

I looked at a colleagues machine on which he has it working. Inside the "Debug" folder I found these 4 files:

1. App.baml
2. App.compressed
3. Mainpage.baml
4. Mainpage.compressed

I am new to Silverlight. Could someone kindly explain as to why these files are not being generated when I build my VC++ project.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

There is a *.xrpack file within the project with the following line in it:

```
# Uncomment /C to force xrpack to perform a clean build every time
#/C
```

If you changed #/C to /C the *.baml and *.compressed files will be generated on each build.